# show json in json as 2 cubes side by side in a row and not as a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, dictionary

I have a json item that has an array inside with no key, like this:

```
"id": "81,
"title": " Web Developer",
"creationTime": 1542111235544,
"labels": ["Corvid", "Api"]
```

where the lables is the array.

I want to diaplay it as 2 cubes in a row, but I dont now how, I iterate it with a map but its shoing list of cubes instead.

here is my code of the labels array:

```
<ul className='labels'>
    {ticket.labels.map(s => (<li > 
        {<button style={{background:'#e6ffe6',border: '0px solid', }}> {s } </button>} 
        </li>))}
         </ul>
```

[Here is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh9Ax.png)

[here what I get now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5COK.png)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the react code that will help you now.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to write CSS for that. Your code seems to be correct for the react.js JSX. You can try changing the CSS as I have shown below for the normal HTML:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
}

ul li button {
  background-color: #deeffc;
  border: 1px solid #d3e9fb;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #636574;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button>Corvid</button></li>
  <li><button>Api</button></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the running code that you are looking for:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       ticket: {
        "id": "81",
        "title": " Web Developer",
        "creationTime": 1542111235544,
        "labels": ["Corvid", "Api"]
       }
     }
   }
  render() {
    let {ticket} = this.state;
    return(
       <div>
        <ul className='labels'>
    {ticket.labels.map(s => (<li> 
        {<button className='ul-btn'> {s } </button>} 
        </li>))}
         </ul>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.ul-btn {
  background-color: #e6ffe6;
  border: 0px solid;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #636574;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `li`.

To align the `li` elements horizontally, Apply this style to the `li`.

```css
float: left;
```

And to remove the circle icon, Apply this to `ul`

```css
list-style-type: none;
```

**OR**

Use `<span>`/ `<label>` instead of `<li>`.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!